# Unable to deploy to iOS device: Failed to resolve "System.Configuration.ConfigurationException"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

As for now, my Xamarin Form App solution:

```
|___MyDomain.Mobile
|
|___MyDomain.Mobile.Android
|
|___MyDomain.Mobile.iOS
```

Using VS 2015, I'm able to build and deploy to simulator (6, 6s, 7, 7s, ipad, etc...) just fine. But when I tried to build and deploy to my iOS devices (iPad and iPhone) using a free provisioning profile, I got the following error:

```
2>  Generated session id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2>  Generated build app name: MyDomain.Mobile.iOS
2>  Connecting to Mac server 10.0.0.131...
2>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
2>I:\_VSWorkSpace\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile.iOS\Main.cs(21,30,21,31): warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used
2>  MyDomain.Mobile.iOS -> I:\_VSWorkSpace\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\MyDomain.MobileiOS.exe
2>  Detected signing identity:
2>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Developer: xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com (xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
2>    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
2>    Bundle Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2>    App Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(696,3): error : Failed to resolve "System.Configuration.ConfigurationException" reference from "System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
Build started.
Build FAILED.
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

As for error, the Linker was set to the default option "Link SDK assemblies only". Trying "Don't Link" gave me the following error:

```
2>  Generated session id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2>  Generated build app name: MyDomain.Mobile.iOS
2>  Connecting to Mac server 10.0.0.131...
2>  No way to resolve conflict between "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "System.Runtime.Serialization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
2>I:\_VSWorkSpace\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile.iOS\Main.cs(21,30,21,31): warning CS0168: The variable 'e' is declared but never used
2>  MyDomain.Mobile.iOS -> I:\_VSWorkSpace\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile\MyDomain.Mobile.iOS\bin\iPhone\Debug\MyDomain.MobileiOS.exe
2>  Detected signing identity:
2>    Code Signing Key: "iPhone Developer: xxxxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com (xxxxxxxxxxxxxx)" (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
2>    Provisioning Profile: "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
2>    Bundle Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2>    App Id: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
2>  AOT Compilation exited with code 1, command:
2>  MONO_PATH=/Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/10.3.1.8/bin/arm64-darwin-mono-sgen --debug -O=gsharedvt  --aot=mtriple=arm64-ios,data-outfile=/Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Configuration.arm64.aotdata,static,asmonly,direct-icalls,full,soft-debug,dwarfdebug,no-direct-calls,outfile=/Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/System.Configuration.dll.arm64.s "/Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.Configuration.dll"
2>  Mono Ahead of Time compiler - compiling assembly /Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.Configuration.dll
2>  AOTID 235E9A81-6AF1-63FB-1A9A-E60B79A8A7FA
2>  Failed to load method 0x600019c from '/Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.Configuration.dll' due to Could not resolve type with token 01000047 assembly:System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 type:System.Configuration.ConfigurationException member:<none>.
2>  Run with MONO_LOG_LEVEL=debug for more information.
2>  AOT of image /Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.Configuration.dll failed.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(696,3): error : Could not AOT the assembly '/Users/victornguyen/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/MyDomain.Mobile.iOS/848068465550219d0aabc577444792b2/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/System.Configuration.dll'
========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

"Link all assemblies" option didn't result in any build error, but when I deployed my app, it was just a blank screen. I believe this was due to the "Default constructor not found for type MyDomain.Mobile.ViewModels.LoginViewModel" error, which I also got if I tried to build the project in this mode targeting simulator.

Initially, within the parent solution, I also had a MyDomain.Mobile.API project which is basically a web server where my app will make API calls to. This project does reference System.Configuration.dll, and uses System.dll version 4.0.0. My understanding is that when linking assemblies and packaging the final app to device, this API project should not interfere with the MyDomain.Mobile.iOS one (which uses another version of System.dll of 2.0.5.0) since it doesnt have any dependency to this MyDomain.Mobile.API. Regardless, since I ran into this System.Configuration reference issue, I went ahead and moved this API project to somewhere else (outside of this solution) and built the iOS one again (using all 3 linker options) just to see if it makes any difference. And it still gave me the exact same error.....

Could someone give me any pointer on how to fix this? Bottom line is that I cant seem to deploy to iOS devices; no problem for simulator.

I have another XF app using exact same version of Xlabs Forms (2.3.0-pre02) and Xamarin 2.3.1.114, and it built and compiled just fine on both devices and simulators

---

I also noticed 1 other thing which is that inside MyDomain.Mobile, there's a reference to MyDomain.Data: this is basically a dll of logic objects imported from another shared project. I believe this might have been cause of the issue, because inside this dll there is definitely reference to System.Configuration. I shall go ahead and discuss with my team and see if we can try moving some of the stuffs around and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: Just to make sure, did you clean the whole solution with a full rebuild after moving the API solution?

Comment: @hankide I did: I removed the API project from solution explorer, then went to where its located and moved it to another folder outside the solution, restarted VS, cleaned the solution and rebuilt it, the same error popped up

Comment: I have the same issue, some assembly added that have System.Configuration. Some solution founded? Mine is pcl net-standard 2.0, thank's!

Comment: I just remove all system.configuration from the assemblies, but i get the same issue. Don't know why.

Comment: @soydachi: The first step is to make sure that each assembly reference does not reference System.Configuration within itself (I had 2 of those in my original project). Then clean and rebuild. I already fixed this issue by refactoring some codes so that none of the references depend on System.Configuration

Comment: What if we dont want to remove the system.configuration references though? How can we make it support them?